# Entity Framework 4 + Silverlight persisting entity graphs

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework-4, persistence

we are currently building our first large application with Silverlight 4 (using PRISM) and Entity Framework 4. Now I'm having a general question about persisting view model data.
Suppose I have domain objects which translate to EF4 entities with multiple associations (Entity having collections, having collections again etc..). What would be the best way to persist those graphs during / after user actions? Would it be better to write more granular repository methods like "AddEntityToParent" and "RemoveEntityFromParent" or just take all the data from the view and push it to a "SaveLargeParentEntity" Method? 
Can I "cache" the view model items for child objects in Silverlight and push it all down to EF4 later or would I have to make a granular update for every single item changed in the user interface? Any good advise? I hope my question was clear enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually making a choice between basic CRUD operations and working with object graphs. I would choose second approach because [CRUD operations over web service can be very chatty.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931661/why-are-crud-operations-so-bad-in-a-soa-design/3931726#3931726)

When working with object graphs send over web service you have to deal with detached behavior. Detached entities + object graph [couses some troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/3635326#3635326) when updating relations. The best approach usually is to load the whole graph before update (get attached entities) and merge received graph into attached one - it will correctly track changes for you.

But because you are using Silverlight which is stateful you can also think about using Self tracking entities (STE). STEs are able to track changes after they are detached from EF ObjectContext. So you can return object graph consisted of STEs from web service to Silverlight application, make some changes to STEs and send same object graph back to web service. [Applying changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638650/ef4-ste-reattaching-via-a-wcf-service-using-a-new-objectcontext-each-and-ever) from STEs will handle a lot of work for you. Be aware that [STEs are not the best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814706/self-tracking-entities-vs-poco-entities/3815968#3815968) for services which should be exposed to general web applications or non .NET clients.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer!

Comment: When using self tracking entities I must expose those entity classes directly thus tightly coupling my layers...

Comment: @Malkier: Yes that is the drawback of STEs and also the reason why STEs are not usable for .NET clients.